# How to keep and don't warn all external libraries for Proguard setting?

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

I would like to keep all of the external libraries in my project and also don't warn about them at all.

But it seems to me that the only way to do this is for each library, add `-keep` and `-dontwarn` options.

Is there any way to do this? 
I am hoping to do something like this:

-keep class externallibraries.** { *; }
-dontwarn externallibraries.**

Any advice or comment is welcomed.

Comment: Please add your projects build.gradle code.